# SQL query to get time gap in different events

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm looking to solve a problem in my application without elegant solution.

I have a table like this:

```
ItemId | StartDateTime       | EndDateTime         | StartState | EndState
   1   | 2017-01-01 12:00:00 | 2017-01-01 12:30:00 |     1      |    0
   1   | 2017-01-03 08:00:00 | 2017-01-03 09:00:00 |     0      |    1
   1   | 2017-01-08 10:00:00 | 2017-01-08 10:30:00 |     1      |    1
   1   | 2017-01-15 14:00:00 | 2017-01-14 10:30:00 |     1      |    0
   1   | 2017-02-01 09:30:00 | 2017-02-01 10:00:00 |     0      |    1
```

I need a query to sum all the gap between an EndState from 0 to 1 in a month. 
At the time, I perform a loop in c# to get the gaps for the different condition:

1. when an item have only EndState to 0 in a month (full month out)
2. when an item have only EndState to 1 in a month (full month in)
3. when an item have only one EndState to 0 in a month (the gap between the EndDateTime and end of the month)
4. when an item have an EndState to 1 and a StartState to 0 in a month (the gap between the start of the month and the EndDateTime).

It's possible to have this information via a single query or a stored procedure instead looping in c#?

Comment: Can you provide examples, either through the data provided or another sample set of data, that explains your need? For example, given your requirements, what would be the anticipated outcome from the five provided entries in your table?

Comment: Ok. Sorry for my bad explanation. So, the result I want to obtain is: 

Item 1 is out in january for 19 days, 6 hours and 30 minutes 
(1d 20h 30m from 01/01/2017 12:30:00 to 03/01/2017 09:00:00 plus 17d 10h from 14/01/2017 10:30:00 to 01/02/2017 00:00:00 end of the january)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a start - but your requirement of interpreting the end of a month when it falls within the start/end times is left up to you:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
;with ordered( itemid, startdatetime, enddatetime, startstate, endstate, rownum ) as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by itemid 
                                 order by itemid, startdatetime) 
      from inventory
),
goneOut( itemid, startdatetime, enddatetime, startstate, endstate, rownum ) as (
    select goneOut.* 
      from ordered goneOut
     where goneOut.startstate = 1 and goneOut.endstate = 0
),
comeBack( itemid, startdatetime, enddatetime, startstate, endstate, rownum ) as (
    select goneOut.* 
      from ordered goneOut
     where goneOut.startstate = 0 and goneOut.endstate = 1
),
rangeOut ( itemid, goneOutRowNum, comeBackRowNum ) as (
    select goneOut.itemid, goneOut.rownum, min(comeBack.rownum)
      from goneOut 
            inner join comeBack 
                on goneOut.itemid = comeBack.itemid
               and goneOut.rownum < comeBack.rownum
     group by goneOut.itemid, goneOut.rownum
),
rangeTimeBits ( itemid, startdatetime, enddatetime, totalMinutes, days, hours, minutes ) as (
    select r.itemid, g.enddatetime, c.enddatetime, 
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, g.enddatetime, c.enddatetime),
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, g.enddatetime, c.enddatetime) / (24 * 60),
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, g.enddatetime, c.enddatetime) % (24 * 60) / 60,
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, g.enddatetime, c.enddatetime) % (24 * 60) % 60
      from rangeOut r
            inner join goneOut g on r.itemid = g.itemid and r.goneOutRowNum = g.rownum
            inner join comeBack c on r.itemid = c.itemid and r.comeBackRowNum = c.rownum
)
select * from rangeTimeBits
```

The final select will give you the start/end times for when an item has 0 state along with the individual day/hour/minute breakdown of each outage. Surely, from this point, you can ascertain how to filter out end-of-month and/or aggregate the individual item outages.

```
itemid  startdatetime           enddatetime             totalMinutes days hours minutes
1       2017-01-01 12:30:00.000 2017-01-03 09:00:00.000 2670         1    20    30
1       2017-01-14 10:30:00.000 2017-02-01 10:00:00.000 25890        17   23    30
```